# How can I change the font color of an accordion menu in a shiny app?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I want to recreate the following accordion menu: [image: Accordion menu inside of a tabPanel]

I am using the `accordion()` function from the `shinydashboardPlus` package, and got to here so far:

[image]

I am trying to change the font color to black to match the first image, but adding the following CSS code is not working:

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
        .box-title {
          color: black !important;
        }
      ")
    )
  )
```

If someone could help me to change the font color, and if possible to add the well (AKA: the white rectangle with circled borders around each item of the accordion menu) it would be great!

Here is te full app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
        .box-title {
          color: black !important;
        }
      ")
    )
  ),
  accordion(
    id = "covenants",
    accordionItem(
      title = "Cash on cash",
      status = "danger",
      collapsed = TRUE,
      "This is some text!"
    ),
    accordionItem(
      title = "Net Portfolio Yield Percentage",
      status = "warning",
      collapsed = TRUE,
      "This is some text!"
    ),
    accordionItem(
      title = "Minimum Liquidity Amount",
      status = "warning",
      collapsed = TRUE,
      "This is some text!"
    ),
    accordionItem(
      title = "Maximum Debt to Equity Ratio",
      status = "warning",
      collapsed = TRUE,
      "This is some text!"
    ),
    accordionItem(
      title = "Most Favored Nation",
      status = "warning",
      collapsed = TRUE,
      "This is some text!"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.box-title` selector targets the title of the accordion, which is usually a hyperlink. By default, hyperlinks have a special style that includes a different color for visited and unvisited links. The color property only applies to unvisited links, whereas the :visited selector can be used to target visited links

Therefore, the correct CSS code is:

```
.box-title a {
  color: black !important;
}
```